# How to create a portable/bootable Windows 10/11 from Linux? (not installer)

Tags: linux, windows-10, portable

For a firmware update that is only provided as Windows executable by the vendor <sub>(Asus motherboard USB-C PD firmware [here](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1700/ROG%20STRIX%20Z690-I%20GAMING%20WIFI/ROG_STRIX_Z690-I_GAMING_WIFI_PD_FW_Update_Tool_V005.zip))</sub>, I need to have a temporary Windows installation. All the tutorials on how to create a USB flash drive to get a temporary/portable Windows installation that I find ([1](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-portable-windows-go-usb-drive/), [2](https://www.easeus.com/todo-backup-resource/create-portable-windows-usb-drive.html), [3](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-run-windows-10-from-a-usb-drive)) are using Windows tools. None seem cross-platform. However, I don't have any current Windows PC at home, it's all Linux.  So there you have it; a chicken-and-egg problem.

*N.B. I'm not looking for a bootable Windows installer, I need to get a **running** Windows install instead to perform some Administrator-enabled commands running a .exe to flash a device. Ie. the equivalent of a Linux live desktop image.*

Is it really 2022 and that complicated that I have to do something like this?

1. download some Windows test/dev VM (for a completely different use case like [this one](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/)),
2. convert the virtual disk to some virtualization disk image format used in Linux,
3. set it up with USB redirection or something to get the actual USB flash drive in there, then
4. in the VM download another Windows ISO with tools to flash the drive?

I feel like I'm missing something, is it really *that* much magic the Windows-only tools are doing or can I perform some steps directly to create a portable Windows 10/11 drive from Linux/Ubuntu?

Comment: I would just use a Windows VM and run Rufus within to create the installation media on a flash drive.  However, Windows 2 Go installations are extremely slow even on the newest CPUs and was discontinued by Microsoft about 2 years ago.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not looking for a way to create installation media (read the question again), but I think I get your point.

Comment: Sorry;  I used the phrase installation media, I meant to say a Windows 2 Go installation on the flash drive.  Rufus is still your best option.  However, you might find it easier, to just install an entirely different disk in your system and disconnect your current disks.  I will again repeat Windows 2 Go was discontinued because it has horrible performance.  We are talking triple digit boot times (seconds).

Comment: Got it! By the way, "triple digit boot times (seconds)" is totally fine; I just need a single time to boot Windows. I bet a full installation takes a lot longer to finish, and the hassle of swapping disks. 

Comment: BTW, AOEMEI has a path to create Windows To Go, https://www.diskpart.com/win2go/windows-to-go-tool-5740i.html . Perhaps it could be put on a fast SSD, and would not be *quite* so lethargic.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to use
[Hiren’s BootCD PE](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/),
which is basically a portable and bootable Windows environment:

> Hiren’s BootCD PE (Preinstallation Environment) is a restored edition
> of Hiren’s BootCD based on Windows 10 PE x64. Since there are no
> official updates after November 2012, PE version is being developed by
> Hiren’s BootCD fans. It contains the fewest but best free tools. It is
> being developed for the new age computers, it supports UEFI booting
> and requires a minimum of 2 GB RAM.
>
> With the useful tools inside of the CD, you can fix many problems
> related to your computer. It does not contain any pirated software, it
> contains only free and legal software.
>
> After boot, PE version tries to install drivers like graphics, sound,
> wireless and ethernet card for your hardware. So that you can connect
> to a WIFI or Ethernet network. Please Contact Us with your hardware
> model if your WIFI or Ethernet card is not recognized by the PE
> version. We will try to add the required drivers in the new releases.

[image]

You will find more bootable Windows PE bootable CDs in the article
[5 Bootable Windows PE ISO To Boot, Recover And Repair Windows](https://www.geckoandfly.com/32030/bootable-windows-pe-recovery-repair/).

This includes : MediCat USB, Sergei Strelec’s WinPE,
All in One – System Rescue Toolkit,
Gandalf’s Windows 10PE (donation required).

Comment: Thanks, and how would you create the usb stick from a linux environment in each case? Just dd?

Comment: Use any method, same as creating a bootable Linux USB. See for example [10 Useful Tools to Create Bootable USB from an ISO Image](https://www.tecmint.com/linux-bootable-usb-creators/) (check the ones for Linux).

Comment: Thanks. Hiren's Boot CD seems not updated for a while (last update July 2021). That seems a little too old for my 2022 hardware to be supported out of the box, but I could try.

Comment: All you need is a Windows environment that functions well enough to flash the device. If Hiren's Boot is not good enough, there are alternatives in the link at the end of my answer.

Comment: @gertvdijk: Did you manage to create a working stick? If so, which image did you use and which method to create the stick from linux? I tried [woeusb-gui](https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB) (as sudo) and Hiren PE. It booted but ended at a screen where windows told me to insert a windows installation cd.

Comment: Honesty @harrymc, when I just saw this .. I was thinking "did I write this?"  until I scrolled down as saw it was you.  I have been using Hiren's since the beginning (when it had illegal software on it and based on DOS).  To this day, we use this at work to troubleshoot and update machines when nothing else makes sense.  Excellent "portable windows" for most purposes and it is easy to add things to it as long as they will run under the PE environment.

Comment: v1.0.2 did not work well for me. I started in safe mode (with networking), but Chrome and Firefox had non-functional shortcuts (blank icons) and while IE was able to access webpages, the browser could not download (and the downloads menu could not be opened, Ctrl +J). Powershell appeared not to be present and I didn't bother finding out whether Firefox can be downloaded via FTP using the CMD.

Comment: https://medicatusb.com/ (mentioned in the answer) appears to be a potential successor, ships with the Windows PE environment as well. Official torrent as one  download method.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact need and I was able to install Windows to an external USB drive from Linux by running the Widows installation in VirtualBox: [Is it possible to flash firmware through a VM?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/749508/14436)

At that answer I also linked to a tool that can be used to install Windows from Linux without running the Windows installation (`deploy-win10-from-linux`)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Download Windows ISO (you can do that with Rufus in Windows) and write it to pendrive with `dd`. Modern computer should understand that medium and should boot from it - there you have installer.
2. Use Rufus on Windows to create Windows To Go pendrive and you have fully working system. You should update it in Windows Update.

On Linux there are no simple options to create Windows medium that would be bootable as a system (not installer). Eventually you can download ISO with Linux (from Microsoft page) and go for point 1.

Other option is to mess around with Windows on disk and try to put it to pendrive but this takes much work and is complicated.

Creating a Windows To Go is several minutes on Windows, so you can do that at your friend's house.

Other option is to use pre-build environment, which are downloadable on the Internet. For example DreamOS.

To create a Windows To Go without Rufus, you would need to take many steps. It is possible, but complicated. Last steps would be to write bootloader for your pendrive system.

Rufus is usually here: https://rufus.ie/en/

Comment: Using `dd` is inadequate: even though Windows is able to boot from a USB stick with ISO 9660 filesystem and successfully mounts it as a disk drive X:, the installer pretends it does not see the source medium and needs a driver to be loaded (the so called “F6 floppy”). It requires its files to be extracted on a FAT or NTFS filesystem, and that is exactly what specialized tools do. (NTFS is more robust, as some files in recent Windows versions may be larger than 4 GiB.)